# Abstract algebraic geometry vs complex algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question

Sorry in advance if my question is not precise enough.

I'm currently trying to study algebraic geometry on my own. I've started by trying to read Harsthorne and Liu's book. And i found it very difficult, especially because every proof seemed "clever" and non intuitive. I'd say that i wouldn't have been able to find any of them, especially the ones of real theorems like the one on formal functions, for instance.
I felt a bit discouraged, and i told myself, well algebraic geometry is hard.

The i ran into the book of griffith harris, principles of algebraic geometry... and it was simply incredible, the book felt really natural to read, and i felt like i was really doing geometry.

So i'ma  bit perplexed because i've heard several times, that schemes make things simpler and more natural and that it is clearly the good way of seeing things. I remember something from Harris book, "the geoemtry of shemes", which went like "The expert do know that schemes often make things simpler".

So i want to know if that's normal that i find scheme theory a lot more obscure than complex geometry, and that i feel that i'm really not able to prove anything in that setting, when i feel i'm a lot more at ease with complex algebraic geometry. And how to convince myself that really schemes are a simplification of classical material, and not an obscure and technical treatment.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, almost inherently, general algebraic geometry is 'more difficult' than complex geometry, since it often times involves abstractifications of concepts in the latter. Defining simple things like dimension is a much more sophisticated and nuanced thing. The idea that they are a simplification of the classical material is misleading. This does not mean that all of complex geometry is simplified by the treatment of general algebraic geometry. What it means is that if you talk about roughly the same type of objects that modern algebraic geometry discusses, but using the classical language

Comment: you quickly become bogged down. It's really difficult to talk about fine structural results using classical language. In essence, trying to talk about varieties over non alg. closed fields is like trying to keep track of a space (the variety over the closure), and the action of a group (the Galois group) at the same time. It's in this sense, things like discussing varieties over non-alg. closed fields, that the modern language provides a simplification of--not necessarily the geometry of complex manifolds. Also, Qing Liu's arguments tend to be disgustingly clever--no mere mortal should expect

Comment: to or come up with all of them on their own. Sometimes his arguments are so far removed from the 'natural argument' (usually with the advantage of being shorter), that they are almost the 'wrong' argument to see for the first time. This is just my opinion though, of course. If you're interested in more down-to-earth approaches, I'd try Vakil or Gortz/Wedhorn.